# Where can I find an Albion Agent like this in Watch Dogs Legion?

Tags: watch-dogs-legion

I was watching a tutorial on YouTube about the Relic in The Roman Wall, and the player was using this Albion Agent:

[image]

Where can I find an Albion Agent like this in London?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like an Albion Elite Captain, very similar in appearance to the Elite Contractor. It seems they start spawning after the "Skye Larsen" storyline, and they become more prevalent in Albion locations after the “Inside Albion” story arc.

Potential locations include:

- Tower of London, head office
- Tower Bridge, telecommunications center
- Nexus Tower, technology center
- Palace of Westminster, seat of the British Parliament
- Royal Courts of Justice, court building of the English High Court and Court of Appeals of England and Wales
- New Scotland Yard, Metropolitan Police headquarters
- Albion Station Camden
- Albion Station Wapping
- Albion Station Bethnal Green
- Albion Station Kennington
- Albion Station Nine Elms

This YouTube video demonstrates the location of one such agent in Westminster:

The channel has other related videos on the location and recruitment of such agents.